# Get data from datalist to another page using session showing error input string is not in correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
if(Session["proid"].ToString() != null && 
   Session["name"].ToString() != null && 
   Session["desc"].ToString() != null && 
   Session["price"].ToString() != null)    
{   
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["proid"].ToString());   
    string proname = Session["name"].ToString();   
    string prodesc = Session["desc"].ToString();   
    string proprice=Session["price"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: where is the logic of assign value to session?

Comment: Looks like your `proid` doesn't have a valid `int` value.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the value of P"proid".
The error can be because of the  string you're trying to parse an integer from doesn't actually contain a valid integer.
**" int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["proid"].ToString());"**